# Tcp/ip communication for opencv in raspberrypi

Tags: c++, sockets, opencv, tcp, raspberry-pi

I have developed a code which detects human in Raspberrypi camera with OpenCV C++ interface. Now, I have to send and display the processed RPI camera Human detection in webpage of browser when the IP address of RPI is entered. Which is similar to Client -Server communication.

After doing some research I found that by using TCP/IP communication the process can be achieved. But I have no idea how to use those protocol communications so that Server side processed video is displayed in client side webpage of browser.

How can I achieve this? Any suggestions or link with related topic wouldbe helpful.

Comment: Do you mean you want the Raspberry Pi to serve regularly updated still images to a client browser, or to stream continuous video?

Comment: hi @MarkSetchell . Thanks for your reply. I need to stream the processed video continuously. Also, how a processed video could be streamed to webpage of the browser of local network if  an ip address of rpi is entered.